# python to c# convert?

Tags: python, c#

Py To C# how can i convert?
Py Code

```
def mygames_login():
 payload = {
   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
   'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
   'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,it-IT;q=0.8,it;q=0.7',
   'Connection': 'keep-alive',
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   'Cookie':'amc_lang=en_US; ',
   'DNT': '1',
   'Host': 'auth-ac.my.games',
   'Origin': 'https://account.my.games',
   'Referer': 'https://account.my.games/oauth2/login/?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccount.my.games%2Foauth2%2F%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fpc.warface.com%252Fdynamic%252Fauth%252F%253Fo2%253D1%26client_id%3Dwf.my.com%26response_type%3Dcode%26signup_method%3Demail%2Cphone%26signup_social%3Dmailru%252Cfb%252Cvk%252Cg%252Cok%252Ctwitch%252Ctw%252Cps%252Cxbox%252Csteam%26lang%3Den_US&client_id=wf.my.com&lang=en_US&signup_method=email%2Cphone&signup_social=mailru%2Cfb%2Cvk%2Cg%2Cok%2Ctwitch%2Ctw%2Cps%2Cxbox%2Csteam',
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'
   }
 login_data = {
   'email':email.get(),
   'password':password.get(),
   'continue':'https://account.my.games/oauth2/?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpc.warface.com%2Fdynamic%2Fauth%2F%3Fo2%3D1&client_id=wf.my.com&response_type=code&signup_method=email,phone&signup_social=mailru%2Cfb%2Cvk%2Cg%2Cok%2Ctwitch%2Ctw%2Cps%2Cxbox%2Csteam&lang=en_US',
   'failure':'https://account.my.games/oauth2/login/?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccount.my.games%2Foauth2%2Flogin%2F%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccount.my.games%252Foauth2%252F%253Fredirect_uri%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fpc.warface.com%25252Fdynamic%25252Fauth%25252F%25253Fo2%25253D1%2526client_id%253Dwf.my.com%2526response_type%253Dcode%2526signup_method%253Demail%252Cphone%2526signup_social%253Dmailru%25252Cfb%25252Cvk%25252Cg%25252Cok%25252Ctwitch%25252Ctw%25252Cps%25252Cxbox%25252Csteam%2526lang%253Den_US%26client_id%3Dwf.my.com%26lang%3Den_US%26signup_method%3Demail%252Cphone%26signup_social%3Dmailru%252Cfb%252Cvk%252Cg%252Cok%252Ctwitch%252Ctw%252Cps%252Cxbox%252Csteam&amp;client_id=wf.my.com&amp;lang=en_US&amp;signup_method=email%2Cphone&amp;signup_social=mailru%2Cfb%2Cvk%2Cg%2Cok%2Ctwitch%2Ctw%2Cps%2Cxbox%2Csteam',
   'nosavelogin':'0'
   }
 while True:
   try:
     r = s.post('https://auth-ac.my.games/auth',headers=payload,data=login_data, allow_redirects=False)
     for i in range(0,5):
       """
       1- Auth redirect to oauth2
       2- Oauth2 redirect to sdc
       3- Generates link to get to sdc token
       4- SDC token redirects to oauth2
       5- Auth link for pc.warface.com is generated
       6- GET auth link for session
       """
       r = s.get(r.headers['location'], allow_redirects=False)
     get_token = s.get('https://pc.warface.com/minigames/user/info').json()
     s.cookies['mg_token'] = get_token['data']['token']
     s.cookies['cur_language'] = op_lang()
   except:
     continue
   break
 notificationSender("Crate Manager","Logged in with My.Games profile")
 main_app()
```

site: https://pc.warface.com/en/
login to this site. I want to get the incoming value. how can I do that

I want to convert this code to c#
how?

c# Convert Help me pls
Bad English Sorry 
I use Google translation

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working for you?

Comment: I want to convert this code completely (C#)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is lazy and I have no idea what's going on ...
for example why you did like this:

```
   for i in range(0,5):
       r = s.get(r.headers['location'], allow_redirects=False)
```

You reassign to `r` variable five times in a useless for loop.
By the way, you can easily write your code in c# syntax

```
while True:
  # stuff
```

turns to

```
while(true)
{
}
```

for Get/Post request do like this:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var content = new StringContent(jsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url, content); // or PostAsync
            if (response != null)
            {
                var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(jsonString);
            }
        }
```

Goodjob